# Opencv Does not show image

Tags: python, opencv

i have a problem with my code when i run, the window open and close and i can see the result. ...................................................................

```
import cv2
import numpy
from os.path import join

imagem = cv2.imread('ImagensLupus/3.jpg')
imagemcinza = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

class CascadeClassifier:

    def __init__(self, glasses=True):
        if glasses:
            self.eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(join('haar', 'haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml'))
        else:
            self.eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(join('haar', 'haarcascade_eye.xml'))

    def get_irises_location(self, imagemcinza):
        eyes = self.eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(imagemcinza, 1.3, 5)  # if not empty - eyes detected
        irises = []

        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            iris_w = int(ex + float(ew / 2))
            iris_h = int(ey + float(eh / 2))
            irises.append([numpy.float32(iris_w), numpy.float32(iris_h)])

        return numpy.array(irises)

class EyerisDetector:

    def __init__(self, image_source, classifier, tracker):
        self.tracker = tracker
        self.classifier = classifier
        self.image_source = image_source
        self.irises = []
        self.blink_in_previous = False
        self.blinks = 0

    def run(self):
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        while k != 27:  # ESC
            frame = self.image_source.get_current_frame()
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            if len(self.irises) >= 2:  # irises detected, track eyes
                track_result = self.tracker.track(old_gray, gray, self.irises, self.blinks, self.blink_in_previous)
                self.irises, self.blinks, self.blink_in_previous, lost_track = track_result
                if lost_track:
                    self.irises = self.classifier.get_irises_location(gray)
            else:  # cannot track for some reason -> find irises
                self.irises = self.classifier.get_irises_location(gray)



            old_gray = gray.copy()
            self.image_source.release()
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imshow("Resultado", imagem)
```

Comment: You're not actually calling the classes, you know

Comment: try `cv2.waitkey(0)` after `cv2.imshow(..)`

Comment: is the problem sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cv2.waitKey()` will display the intended result for a fraction of time.

If you want the results to be displayed as long as you want it to, pass the value `0` as well. This will display the result until another event is triggered (like a keypress). You can find more [on this link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey)

A typical use case would be:

```
#- program --

cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

OR you could display the windows within a `while` loop until a certain key is pressed. In the following, windows are displayed until the `Esc` key is pressed:

```
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == 27:   #--- press 'ESC' to break
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```